# CSS Animation not working (Bounce)

Tags: html, css

I am wondering why my bounce animation no working in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n23Lopon/) but working on my development site. Please check what's wrong with this one. In my development site the arrow bounces but not rotated like what told inside my css class.

```css
.active.ongoing::before {
    content: "\f175";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: #56a4da;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 31px;
    transform: rotate(41deg);
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation:bounce 2s infinite;
    -ms-animation:bounce 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="active ongoing">
</div>
```

Comment: did you make your @keyframes for animation bounce??

Comment: @NelsonTan, Nope, it automatically bounce without using `@keyframes`.

Answer (score 0):

this animation is probably  based on animate.css which probably included in your development site , which you didn't include or specify keyframes in jsfiddle

so you can add this to your css and it will work

```
@keyframes bounce {
  from, 20%, 53%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }

  40%, 43% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! This is what my animation looks like. but without using keyframes. additionally, I wanted to rotate the arrow like on my css.

Comment: you can't add transform:rotate in css , in this case cause the animation is overriding it , if you want to rotate the arrow add rotate to the wanted keyframe after translate , so for example if you want the arrow to roate in 90% point you will edit the code to be like this 
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0) rotate(40deg);

Comment: Looks exactly the same with my above sample code. it rotates but the animation is not working